# Facebook login flow doesn't work for my Android app - web authentication

Tags: android, facebook

I have an android game and have integrated the Android Facebook SDK.  When you ask to login using the fb login button, it pops up chrome to enter your credentials.  If I enter them correctly it simply refreshes the web page, it doesn't redirect back to my app to actually login.

If however I hit the 3 dots upper right of the web page and "request desktop site" and do the same login then it works.

It works fine in the simulator running tiramisu but not on a device running Android 8.1.0 (API level 27).. so some of my users on these older versions aren't able to login without some extra guidance to load the desktop version of that web page.

Anyone run into this?  currently using

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:latest.release'

It appears to pull in 15.1.0 of the library